# What's the difference between שמחה and חדוה?

Tags: words, rosh-hashanah-new-year, shofar, simchah-joy-happiness, vilna-gaon

The *Gra* was quoted to me (I think from the Aderes Eliyah, but I'm not sure) as saying that during the shofar blowing on Rosh HaShanna a person should be in a state of simcha and chedva.

I would like to know the difference between the two.

After a bit of research all I could find was the *Gra* and *Malbim* explaining the difference between simcha and gilah.

> **מלבי"ם**
>
> שמחה - היא תמידית, גיל - בשעת הקציר על ההצלחה. **ישעיה טז י**
>
> **גר"א**
>
> גיל יגיל אבי צדיק - ההבדל שבין גילה לשמחה הוא, כי גילה באה על דבר
>   תמידי ושמחה היא בדבר שנתחדש, כמו בהולד בן לאדם אזי בעת הולדו ישמח
>   אביו, ואחר כך כל ימי הבן גילה לאביו... **משלי כג כד**

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=43422&st=&pgnum=386&hilite=

Comment: See also http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/55088

Answer (score 2):

HaRav Ben-Ẓiyon Muẓafi [writes](http://www.doresh-tzion.co.il/QAShowAnswer.aspx?qaid=93939) (my translation):

> .חדוה תרגום של שמחה
>
> "*Ḥedwah* is a translation of *Simḥah*."

Here is the full, untranslated quotation:

> עיין מלבי"ם ירמיה ט"ז, ט. וישעיהו נ"א, ג. שפירש על פי חז"ל ששון הוא חיצוני, שמחה היא פנימית בלב. 
>   גילה היא שמחה משותפת עם אחרים, רינה היא שירה מתוך שמחת הלב.
>
> דיצה תרגום של ששון כמו שכתב מצודת ציון באיוב מ"א, י"ד. **חדוה תרגום של שמחה**. 
>   אהבה היא ענין שבלב ברגש ובנפש, אחוה היא כאשר האהבה מתעצמת הופכת להרגשת שותפות מוחלטת עם השני.
>
> שלום הוא שלימות שאינו רואה שום חסרון או פגם אצל זולתו, כמו על כל פשעים תכסה אהבה. רעות היא שותפות יותר גבוהה והפיכת בני הזוג לאיש אחד וכמו שמובא בזוהר הקדוש ובדברי האלשיך שהוא מושג לדביקות מוחלטת.

In contrast, HaRav Ḥanokh Ben-Pazi [writes](http://www.meirtv.co.il/site/article?id=1689) (my translation):

> **חדווה** - שמחה המהולה בעצב. דוגמא: כשעולה עזרא מן הגולה וכולם רואים את בניין בית שני, אומר: "ועתה אל תעצבו כי חדוות ה' היא מעוזכם". כי שבי הגולה שביניהם יש מהם שראו את הבית הראשון בתפארתו, מחד שמחים על הבניין החדש, אך לבם כואב על התמעטות קדושתו ותפארתו של הבית השני.
>
> ***Ḥedwah*** - *Simḥah* mixed with sadness. For example, when 'Ezra returns to Ereẓ Yisra'el from the [Babylonian] Exile and all witnessed the building of the Second Temple, 'Ezra [says](http://chabad.org/16515#v=10), "[And now] do not be sad, for the joy of the Lord is your strength." Because, the returnees from exile include those who saw the First Temple in its splendor. On the one hand, they are happy about the Second Temple; but, their hearts ache because of the Second Temple's weakened holiness.