# what is the difference between "sasson" and "simcha"

Tags: words, wedding, simchah-joy-happiness, sheva-brachos

The last of the *Sheva Brachot* (7 blessings) said under the wedding *chuppah*, as well as after benching throughout the rest of the week includes an acknowledgement to G-d for creating both "Sasson" and "Simcha". The blessing also quotes a verse from [Yirmiyahu (Jer.) 33:10](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14262&st=&pgnum=272) referring to the voice of "Sasson" and the voice of "simcha".

Two questions:

- What is the difference in meaning / nuance?
- In the 7th blessing, considering that it mentions different "degrees" of "gladness" (*gilah, rina, etc.*, only these 2 are separated from the rest, and are followed by the words *chatan v'kallah* (bride and groom). Since these two items are connected with the bride and groom, what makes these two more "special" or "unique" from the others?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/45734

Comment: The Artscroll Siddur, on the phrase "שמחים בצאתם וששים בבואם" (that the sun and the moon have *simcha* when they go forth to do HaShem's will, and they have *sasson* on completion of their task) says that *sasson* is greater than *simcha*.

Comment: @Fred - I saw that one, as I was typing my question. Perhaps, a separate issue to raise in Meta (not specific to you) regarding listing a related link to an unanswered question. I understand, somewhat, why you or anyone else does this, but, IMO, it's not too useful, and may even be more confusing.

Comment: @Fred - That can be debated, actually. In some cases, sasson is mentioned before Simcha and other places in reverse. I will IY"H post a question about this.

Comment: Interesting point about the links. I think they can be useful even without an answer, or alternatively, they can direct someone who would answer here to also answer there. But I would definitely encourage you to ask on Meta. | I'm sure it is debatable, but I don't think Artscroll's point was about the order in the phrase. It was about *simcha* being before the act (בצאתם) and *sasson* being afterwards (בבואם). Anyway, I think this is a good, important question (+1'd).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The Vilna Gaon states](http://www.shemayisrael.co.il/yomtov/sukkot/happy.htm) that simcha can exist internally, but sasson is a greater level of simcha where it manifests itself externally through your actions. That's why we say "Yasis alayich elokayich kimisos chassan al kallah" - during the wedding he is more than happy, he is "overjoyed."

Comment: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_3380_355.pdf

Comment: @GershonGold and Isaac Kolitcky: Yasis Alayikh is from Lekha Dodi, and composed about Shabbos. It is a paraphrase of a pasuq in Yashaiah. But we only borrowed to refer to marriage. I don't think the Vilna Gaon would have heard "yasis alayikh", I think it's a modern songwriter's idea. And actually, if you look at the original pasuq, you would be really uncomfortable singing it at weddings. Yeshaiah 62:5: כִּֽי־יִבְעַ֤ל בָּחוּר֙ בְּתוּלָ֔ה יִבְעָל֖וּךְ בָּנָ֑יִךְ וּמְשׂ֤וֹשׂ חָתָן֙ עַל־כַּלָּ֔ה יָשִׂ֥ישׂ עָלַ֖יִךְ אֱלֹהָֽיִךְ׃ https://www.sefaria.org/Isaiah.62.5?lang=bi

Comment: Along the same lines as the Gra's point... Kedarko baqodesh, R' Hirsch notes the similarity between a group of sibilant-semivowel-sibilant words: זוז - move [slowly, which RSRH connects to doorpost in ways I find tenuous], סוס - an animal used for rapid locomotion, and שוש - to rejoice to the point of physical expression.

Answer (score 2):

[R. Shmuel Bornsztain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shmuel_Bornsztain_(second_Sochatchover_rebbe)) explains that Simcha is joy that comes about gradually and with equanimity, while Sasson is a sudden burst of joy. Sasson is a stronger form of joy but it does not last long. Simcha is a weaker form of joy but it is long-lasting.

**[Shem M'Shmuel Yom Hakipurim Year 5672](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=43721&st=&pgnum=139&hilite=)**

בש"ס סוכה הנהו תרי מיני חד שמי' ששון וחד שמי' שמחה א"ל ששון לשמחה אנא עדיפנא מינך דכתיב ששון ושמחה ישיגו וגו' א"ל שמחה לששון אנא עדיפנא מינך דכתיב שמחה וששון ליהודים, א"ל ששון לשמחה חד יומא שבקוך ושויוך פרוונקא דכתיב כי בשמחה תצאו א"ל שמחה לששון חד יומא שבקוך ומלו בך מיא דכתיב ושאבתם מים בששון א"ל האי מינא דשמי' ששון לר' אבהו עתידיתו דתמלו לי מים לעלמא דאתי דכתיב ושאבתם מים בששון א"ל אי הוה כתיב לששון כדקאמרת השתא דכתיב בששון משכי' דההוא גברא משוינן לי' גודא ומלינן בי' מיא והמאמר פלאי והמהרש"א פירש שבדרך היתול אמר מין אחד לחברו כן ודבריו אינם מובנים כי תורתנו הקדושה איננה מקום להעתיק בה דברי התולים ובודאי עניני חכמה ולימוד לאדם נרמזו כאן ומפי כ"ק אבי אדמו"ר זצללה"ה שמעתי שאמר לפרש דהמין סבר כי התכלית לאדם להיות שש ושמח והשיב לו ר' אבהו כי זה רק צורך לעבודה ולא התכלית וזהו שמרמז משכי' דההוא גברא משוינן לי' גודא ומלינן בי' מיא ודפח"ח

ולפי דרכו יש לפרש כל המשא והמתן מה שבין המינים ובין המין לר"א על דרך זה דהנה שמחה היא הבאה לאדם בהדרגה וישוב הדעת וששון הוא הבא פתאום וכן נראה ממאמר הכתוב שש אנכי על אמרתך כמוצא שלל רב והנה מציאה היא דבר הבא פתאום לאדם בלתי התכוון אליו מקודם ע"כ נקרא שש ושש וששון הם מגזירה אחת והנה ידוע שהפילסופים פקרו במצוות מעשיות באמרם שהתכלית היא רק שהנפש תקנה מדות טובות ובשיטתם זאת הלכו גם המינים האלו והם ביניהם חלקו רק מה טוב יותר אם שמחה הבאה בהדרגה וישוב הדעת שנתעצם בנפש [כי הכל מודים שהעצבות היא תכונה רעה בנפש] או ששון הבא פתאום כי באשר בא פתאום נרגשת הנפש יותר ומייתי ששון מקרא ששון ושמחה ישיגו דאקדים קרא ששון לשמחה והיינו שע"י הששון שנרגשת הנפש פתאום יבוא אח"כ גם לשמחה בישוב הדעת. ושמחה מייתי מקרא שמחה וששון ליהודים, היינו שע"י השמחה בהדרגה וישוב הדעת שנתעצם בנפש תבוא אח"כ גם לששון שתתרגש הנפש ותתלהב בדבר קל כידוע מכחות הנפש שכאשר הנפש תתרגל באהבה וכדומה בהתלהבות אז בסיבה קלה תתלהב באהבה כפתיל הנעורת בהריחו אש

ובענין זה יש מקום לדברי שניהם שבאמת לכל אחד יש מעלה מה שאין בזולתו שששון הבא פתאום יש בו רגש יותר מאילו הי' בה בהדרגה אבל לעומת שבא כן ילך בין לילה הי' ובין לילה אבד ושמחה הבאה בהדרגה יש בה מעלה שמתקיימת ביותר אבל איננה כ"כ ברגש חזק וע"כ הובאו דבריהם בש"ס אבל בעיקר הדבר שתפסו במשלם שזה תכלית האדם בא ר' אבהו והכה על קדקדם שלא כן הדבר רק כמו נאד לשאוב בו מים, ואם יהי' לאיש נאד מוכן אבל לא ישאב בו מים רק יעמידנו אצלו ריקם ימות בצמא כן הוא זה שהנפש תשאר ריקה ונעורה ותלך לאבדון ולא יועילו לה השמחה והששון שהיו לה בעודה בזה העולם וכמו שמסיים שלמה המע"ה ספר קהלת את אלקים ירא ואת מצותיו שמור כי זה כל האדם

Answer (score 1):

The Malbim (see [here](http://forum.otzar.org/viewtopic.php?t=8851) for a list of sources where he says this) explains that Simcha is happiness in the heart (i.e. inwards), whereas Sasson is "outward", revealed happiness/celebration.

Edit: I just stumbled upon [a source](http://www.chabad.org.il/Magazines/Article.asp?ArticleID=807&CategoryID=444) paraphrasing the Lubavitcher Rebbeh, who suggests that the opposite is true, namely that Sasson is inwards, and Simcha outwards, (but he agrees that Sasson is a "stronger happiness" although for a different reason):

> אולם בעיון יתר מגלים כי מדובר בחילוק הקשור בעצם המהות: "שמחה" קשורה בעניינים חיצוניים, ו"ששון" קשור לעניינים פנימיים. כתוצאה מכך **ה"שמחה" היא בגלוי וה"ששון" בהעלם, מכיוון שעניין חיצוני (שמחה) מוליד שמחה גלויה ואילו עניין פנימי (ששון) מוליד שמחה מסותרת.**

Comment: It's a different source, but, essentially, you've repeated the previous answer. Can you add anything different from Malbim?

Comment: @DanF I hadn't noticed that - I thought it was simply the intensity of the happiness.  Regardless, I am about to add another source.